# Concatenate references of duplicate values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (chapter) that contains 5 columns for officers in an organization: ID (key), president, vice_president, secretary, treasurer. For each office there is the value of a reference number to an individual.

For some IDs, the same value is listed for more than one of the 4 offices. You can see a basic example of my data structure below:

```
ID      president   vice_president  secretary   treasurer
105     1051456     1051456         1051466     1051460
106     1060923     1060937         1060944     1060944
108     1081030     1081027         1081032     1081017
110     1100498     1100491         1100485     1100485
```

I have also posted the same at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57df1

My goal is to identify when a value is in more than one field and to SELECT that value as well as a concatenated list of all of the column titles in which it is found. For example from the supplied sample dataset, I would ideally like to return the following:

```
member    offices
1051456   president, vice_president
1060944   secretary, treasurer
1100485   secretary, treasurer
```

I have found a few other examples that are similar, but nothing seems work towards what I am looking to do. I'm a novice but can piece things together from examples fairly well. I was also thinking that there might be an easier way by joining with the information_schema database as that is how I have pulled column titles in the past. It doesn't seem that this should as difficult as it is, and hopefully I am missing an easy and obvious solution. My full dataset is rather large and I would prefer to avoid any intensive sub-queries for the sake of performance. My SQL format is MySQL 5.5.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What would happen if there was a CEO or Bursar or Financial Director, say?

Comment: As far as I know, there is now way to "group" or count instances of values within a row. As I think Strawberry is hinting, you are better off with a different table structure (think a table with fields something like org, ref_number, position; and multiple rows for each org). _Edit: Gordon's answer basically converts your current structure into such a format and does the operation on that instead._

Comment: @Strawberry . . . These offices are actually legal definitions for a corporation (at least in the United States).  CEO, Bursar, and Financial Director sound more like job titles than corporate officers.

Comment: If you didn't know their position, and you wanted to remove them, and you didn't know the company, yikes.

Comment: @gordonlinoff ok, fair enough, but I think you know where I was heading...

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a good study in how it can be hard to deal with denormalized data.  You'd be better off with a an officers table with columns of (company_id, position_id, member_id) And then you could `GROUP BY member_id,company_id` and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to make a list of positions.  It'd be a much faster query to run, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `union all` to unpivot the data and then re-aggregates:

```
select member, group_concat(office)
from ((select id, president as member, 'president' as office from t) union all
      (select id, vice_president, 'vice_president' as office from t) union all
      (select id, secretary, 'secretary' as office from t) union all
      (select id, treasurer, 'treasurer' as office from t)
     ) t
group by member
having count(distinct office) > 1;
```

If you want to control the order of the values, then add a priority:

```
select member, group_concat(office order by priority) as offices
from ((select id, president as member, 'president' as office, 1 as priority from t) union all
      (select id, vice_president, 'vice_president' as office, 2 from t) union all
      (select id, secretary, 'secretary' as office, 3 from t) union all
      (select id, treasurer, 'treasurer' as office, 4 from t)
     ) t
group by member
having count(distinct office) > 1;
```